# How to pass additional route parameter in angular?

Tags: angular6, angular-routing

I am working on Angular 6 application and have route survey that is config on app root level and then :id to take it survey detail page, I am trying to navigate from component using

```
 this.router.navigate(['/survey'], this.listedSurvey.surveyIdNum);
```

But I believe I am missing something from router navigate as I am unable to do so.

### App route

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path:'welcome', component:WelcomeComponent },
{ path:'', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch:'full'},
{ path:'survey', loadChildren: '../survey/survey.module#SurveyModule' },
{ path:'**', component:PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [
 RouterModule
 ]
 })

 export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

### survey module

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ 
    path:'', 
    component:SurveyComponent,
},
{
    path:':id',
    component: SurveyFormComponent
 }
];

@NgModule({
 imports:[
     RouterModule.forChild(routes)
 ],
 exports:[]
})
 export class SurveyRouting{
}
```

### component

```
 private handleSelectedSurvey(dataItem:any){
   this.listedSurvey = dataItem;
   const a:number = 2;
   //this.router.navigate(['/survey'], this.listedSurvey.surveyIdNum);
   this.router.navigate(['/survey'],{queryParams:{id:a}}); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the navigate()
`this.router.navigate(['/survey', this.listedSurvey.surveyIdNum]);`

Refer: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate